# How to use localhost (any port) with frontend languages or frameworks?

Tags: javascript, html, css, localhost

I'm making a new website with HTML, CSS, js for frontend and Java for backend (I don't know Java, my friend will do the java part) and I need to use frontend technologies (languages/frameworks) to use `localhost`

I am unable to find frontend technologies for this purpose. I have already tried `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` and node.js but as these are backend I can't use them. Also, I can't change my backend language

Comment: Start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps) and read everything in the guide.

Comment: You can use any backend for development. For production the real backend has to deliver your app

Comment: *I'm making a new website with html, css, js* — *I am unable to find frontend technologies for this purpose*: I think you **have** found frontend technologies, as your browser definitely supports all of those. There's nothing special about `localhost` as part of a URL; it's just a hostname.

Comment: @Pointy I need localhost to test and run

Comment: OK, so run a server on the local machine. It's not clear at all what the problem is.

Comment: @Lux can you please make your point clearer

Comment: @Pointy the problem is I can't use backend to run a server and i don't know any frontend technologies for the purpose

Comment: That makes no sense at all. You can run a server on any computer you have access to. The term "frontend" refers to code in a client (a browser).

Comment: Then how to run a server

Comment: You need to understand that `server` and `backend` are basically synonyms. So how to start a server? well `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` does exactly that: It starts a server.

Comment: But won't it clash with java?

Comment: read my answer for the details. You'll only do it for development, so you have no problem for production. To access the java app in development use either a proxy or CORS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important thing here is that you need to understand the terms *backend* and *frontend*.

A website is by definition something that can be loaded from a server with HTTP and it made of HTML and maybe CSS and/or Javscript.

Now by definition every code that runs on that server is the *backend*. All code that runs in the Browser of the user is considered the *frontend*. If the website only contains HTML and CSS that is generated by the server it does not make much sense to do this seperation. This means we only talk about frontend and backend if we have both.

This also means that the frontend code, that runs in the browser, *must* be delivered by the backend. A frontend without a backend *can not exist*.

Lets look on a little example. If a user enters `example.com` in the browser the browser will make a `HTTP GET` request to `example.com`. The server (and so the backend) will respond with a HTML file. This file now could embed a javascript file with `<script src="/code.js">`. Now the browser does another `HTTP GET` to `example.com/code.js` and the server (and so the backend) returns that file. In that file may be some frontend code that is executed in the browser.
Now maybe this file wants to load some data from the backend. So it does a `fetch('/api/data`)`. The browser does another`HTTP GET`to`example.com/api/data` and the backend has to respond. Now while the backend was relativly dumb up to this point and only delivered files it now could actually execute some logic. Maybe load the data from a database or such. It then sends the data to the frontend which then can use that data to do something.

This means in production your backend *has to* deliver the frontend code. In this example the initial HTML file and the `code.js` file.

So what you want is by definition impossible. A frontend runs in the browser and so can not deliver code on localhost. If it could it would become a backend.

Now while its common that the real backend delivers the frontend code on production its not common for development. Its very common to have a seperate minimalistic server that is only used for development. `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` is such a tool and so would do the job.

Sometimes this is also done in production. Then your backend is for example on `example2.com` and your frontend is delivered by `example.com`. But this essential means that there runs a second backend just to deliver the frontend. Usually for production this is a full fledged web server like `nginx`, `apache` or `IIS` (you'll need CORS, see below). In contrast to them tools like `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` should not be used for production.

Now this means basically you can just use any kind of backend to deliver your frontend for development. Later you will give your code to your backend developer and he will then deploy it with his backend. However there is one open question:

**How will your frontend and backend communicate?**

In production your frontend can just `fetch` something and it will work if your backend delivers your frontend. But for development (and so testing) you probably already want to use the backend without actually starting it on your computer. For this basically there are two ways.

First your development backend could proxy unknown requests to the backend. This means if your real backend runs on `example.com` and you start a development server on `localhost` that server will proxy all requests that are not an existing file to `example.com`. So if you request `localhost/code.js` and the file `code.js` does exist your server will respond with that file. If you request `localhost/data` and you have no file named `data` your server should do a request to `example.com/data` and return that response. This is very common. Depending on the tools, libraries and framework you use for frontend development they have a integrated development server with that capability. For example if you develop with `ember.js` you can do `ember server --proxy=http://example.com`. And it will run a server on `localhost:4200` with exactly that behavior. Other tools like `create-react-app` allow the same.

Second you can use CORS. This must be implemented by the backend and allows a frontend from another server to access the backend. This is also needed if you run your frontend and your backend from two different servers as I described before.
If the backend implemented CORS correctly you can just do `fetch('example.com/data`) to get your data, and this Javascript must not be delivered by `example.com` and it will just work. However CORS complicates security.